# Dynamic Web Project libraries

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, path, libraries

Good morning in my timezone.

I have imported one Dynamic web project to my eclipse. I have downloaded the Tomcat server.
If I work without any IDE, I know that every libraries that we use in the project must be inside the lib folder in tomcat.

> Folder structure : Tomcat\webapps\WEB-INF\lib

My question is, if I need a library (*.jar) should I put it directly in the lib folder or should I configure in the build path, adding it in the libraries tab?

Second question, my project steels have the red cross above the project name, but I do not see where the error is, in the src folder no class have any error and inside the Web Content folder there is not any cross, so how can I know where the problem is?

Thanks in advance.
Best regards developer community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There shouldn't be any need for configuration, just copy them in the lib folder.
2. Make sure you have set the right jdk and the server libraries. right click on `project -> build path -> configure -> libraries`. if there is no tomcat runtime lib, you should add it.(I assume tomcat is embedded in eclipse. If not, right click on servers(next to console) and add the tomcat server.)